# How to create contact form in joomla 3

Tags: joomla3.0

I'm Trying to create custom contact form in Joomla 3 , the reason is I didn't found such big contact form.
Can somebody tell me how to do it ? 
html:

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
<form role="form" method="POST" style="margin-top: 2.7em;" action="">
<div class="row">
<div class="form-group col-lg-4">
<label for="input1">Name</label>
<input type="text" name="contact_name" class="form-control" id="input1">
</div>
<div class="form-group col-lg-4">
<label for="input2">Mail</label>
<input type="email" name="contact_email" class="form-control" id="input2">
</div>
<div class="form-group col-lg-4">
<label for="input3">Phone</label>
<input type="phone" name="contact_phone" class="form-control" id="input3">
</div>
<div class="form-group col-lg-4">
<label for="input1">Dropdown</label>
<select class="form-control" name="bud">
                            <option value="a">parterowy</option>
                            <option value="b">piętrowy</option>
                            <option value="c">bliźniak</option>
                            <option value="c">mieszkalny</option>
                            <option value="c">niemieszkalny</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
                        <label for="input2">Size</label>
                        <input type="email" name="contact_email" class="form-control" id="input2">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
                        <label for="input3">Garage</label>
                        <select class="form-control" name="garaz">
                            <option value="a">wolnostojący</option>
                            <option value="b">w budynku</option>
                            <option value="c">jednostanowiskowy</option>
                            <option value="c">wielostanowiskowy</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
                        <label for="input4">Msg</label>
                        <textarea name="contact_message" class="form-control" rows="6"id="input4"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
                        <input type="hidden" name="save" value="contact">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Send</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>

        </div>
```

[Fiddle to html](http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/1134/)
I read that i need to create custom component or rebuild other, which one is better option ?

Answer (score 1):

As you have already made the html part, the easier way is to implement your code in a [custom module](http://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Creating_a_simple_module/Developing_a_Basic_Module) or for a more advanced result in a [custom component](http://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_a_MVC_Component/Developing_a_Basic_Component).

The official joomla way for adding extra fields to contact form is by [creting a custom plugin](http://docs.joomla.org/Adding_custom_fields_to_core_components_using_a_plugin).

If you want a commercial solution (component) I would suggest you to use [breezingforms](http://crosstec.de/en/).

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Chronoforms](http://www.chronoengine.com/downloads/chronoforms.html) component to create virtually any form you like.

If you need some very special custom output, you can first use the included form bulider to set up the closest approximation and modify it as you like.